# How would I go about creating an MVC application using logins, but no email and no self registration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have searched extensively and have not found an answer.  I need to create an MVC application that uses logins, but I do not want to use email for the username, and there will be no self-registration.  Asp.Net Core or MVC 5 is fine, but I can't find anything for either.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: then use mobile no for registration if user enter mobile no then send OTP as password and allow access to application.

Comment: @Saineshwar Unfortunately that's not an option, the user accounts will be created from a companion desktop application, and the only options the user will have is changing the password or the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple, yet requires several steps. For example:

1. Add the following property to the **LoginViewModel** and **RegisterViewModel** classes:

   [Required]

   [Display(Name = "Username")]

   public string Username { get; set; }
2. Change the **AccountController** **Login action** as follow, model.Email to model.Username

FROM:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

TO:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username,code here model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

3.Change the Login  View to use the new property just created:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Usarname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Usarname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Usarname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

4. Add the Username input to the Register View:

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Usarname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Usarname, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
   ```

Does it for the login part, and to avoid the self registration just remove the links routing to the Register View from the views having it.